# postcss autoprefixer ignoring grid properties with gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp, postcss

i'm using autoprefixer with gulp to add browser render prefix to properties. but seems like autoprefixer ignoring all grid properties.

```js
gulp.task('postcss',function() {

  console.log("Running postcss task");
  var plugins = [autoprefixer({browsers: "last 5 versions"}),orderValues()];
  return gulp.src('www/css/*.css')
              .pipe(postcss(plugins,{ map:true , inline:true }))
              .pipe(gulp.dest("www/css/"));

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is disabled by default. You need to enable it in the options given to Autoprefixer with `grid: true`

[Documentation of Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#disabling)

> Autoprefixer has 4 features, which can be enabled or disabled by options:
>
> - supports: false will disable @supports parameters prefixing.
> - flexbox: false will disable flexbox properties prefixing. Or flexbox: "no-2009" will add prefixes only for final and IE versions of specification.
> - remove: false will disable cleaning outdated prefixes.
> - **grid: true will enable Grid Layout prefixes for IE.**

The decision was made after a vote on Twitter (Issue [#817](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/817)) and the reason behind that is that the old Grid specification implemented in IE10-11 and Edge 12-15 is way too different from the modern one implemented in Chr, Fx, Saf (?) and incoming Edge 16.
You'll need more manual work to achieve an equivalent result on IE10-Edge 15, either a fallback or restraining from using unsupported properties (`grid-area`, etc) and values (`repeat()` I think, etc): in both cases it can't be automatically done by Autoprefixer so nope, disabled by default.

EDIT:
Going farther than your question and answering "What can I do with browsers supporting the old first Grid Layout spec introduced with IE10?":

- [useful table](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) from Rachel Andrew on "IE 10-Edge 15" vs "modern browsers and Edge 16+" grid properties if you want to do it by hand or verify if Autoprefixer is doing it right.
- if you want to separate CSS for those 2 categories of browsers, you can use this gem from [Building Production-Ready CSS Grid Layouts Today](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/06/building-production-ready-css-grid-layout/#side-note-a-word-on-browser-support) article in SmashingMag by Morten Rand-Hendriksen:

  `@supports (grid-area: auto) { /* */ }`

but not `@supports (display: grid) {}` which won't work alas (see article).